# DHCP logs showing (no free leases)

Tags: networking, dhcp-server, isc-dhcp

I have setup new isc-dhcp-server in ubuntu 20.04. all client getting connect but showing there logs (no free leases)

client connected only 25 machine.

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog
Sep  9 09:43:57 ggn-dhcp-srv dhcpd[49319]: DHCPDISCOVER from b6:df:34:66:aa:41 via eth2: network 172.16.136.0/23: no free leases
Sep  9 09:43:58 ggn-dhcp-srv dhcpd[49319]: DHCPDISCOVER from 9a:33:bb:83:f9:16 via eth2: network 172.16.136.0/23: no free leases
Sep  9 09:44:01 ggn-dhcp-srv dhcpd[49319]: DHCPDISCOVER from b6:df:34:66:aa:41 via eth2: network 172.16.136.0/23: no free leases
Sep  9 09:44:05 ggn-dhcp-srv dhcpd[49319]: DHCPDISCOVER from d2:84:01:b4:b1:b8 via eth1: network 172.16.160.0/19: no free leases
Sep  9 09:44:06 ggn-dhcp-srv dhcpd[49319]: DHCPDISCOVER from 9a:33:bb:83:f9:16 via eth2: network 172.16.136.0/23: no free leases
Sep  9 09:44:08 ggn-dhcp-srv dhcpd[49319]: DHCPDISCOVER from d2:84:01:b4:b1:b8 via eth1: network 172.16.160.0/19: no free leases
Sep  9 09:44:09 ggn-dhcp-srv dhcpd[49319]: DHCPDISCOVER from d2:84:01:b4:b1:b8 via eth1: network 172.16.160.0/19: no free leases
Sep  9 09:44:10 ggn-dhcp-srv dhcpd[49319]: DHCPDISCOVER from b6:df:34:66:aa:41 via eth2: network 172.16.136.0/23: no free leases
```

cat /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqra2.png)
so many IPs are free still showing ** no free leases**

Comment: How have you determined that "so many IPs are free"? You can look at `/var/lib/dhcpd/dhcpd.leases` to see what leases have been assigned.

Comment: I have removed and deleted the file still same. I can see list in dhcpd.leases not more then 25 machine

Answer (score 1):

You have `deny unknown-clients` in your pool configuration, which means clients can only receive an address from DHCP if they have a static DHCP reservation defined for their MAC address in a `host` section. I don't see any of those in your posted configuration file.

It sounds like you don't want to use static reservations, so just remove the `deny unknown-clients;` line and restart dhcpd.